# pyspark- generating date sequence

Tags: date, pyspark, sequence, aws-glue

I am trying to generate a date sequence

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn("start_dt", F.to_date(F.col("start_date"), "yyyy-mm-dd")) \
        .withColumn("end_dt", F.to_date(F.col("end_date"), "yyyy-mm-dd"))

df1.select("start_dt", "end_dt").show()
    
print("type(start_dt)", type("start_dt"))
print("type(end_dt)", type("end_dt"))

df2 = df1.withColumn("lineoffdate", F.expr("""sequence(start_dt,end_dt,1)"""))
```

##### Below is the output

```
+---------------+----------+
|   start_date  |  end_date|
+---------------+----------+
|     2020-02-01|2020-03-21|
+---------------+----------+

type(start_dt)  <class 'str'>
type(end_dt)  <class 'str'>
```

**cannot resolve 'sequence(`start_dt`, `end_dt`, 1)' due to data type mismatch: sequence only supports integral, timestamp or date types; line 1 pos 0;**

Even after converting the start dt and end dt to date or timestamp, I see the type of the column still str and getting above mentioned error while generating the date sequence.

Comment: I tried to print the schema 
 |-- start_dt: date(nullable = true)
 |-- end_dt: date(nullable = true)             Dont understand why sequence does not work

Answer (score 6):

You are correct in saying it should work with `date` or `timestamp`(calendar types), however, the only mistake you were making was you were putting the `"step"` in `sequence` as `integer`, when it should be calendar interval(like `interval 1 day`):

```py
df.withColumn("start_date",F.to_date("start_date")) \
  .withColumn("end_date", F.to_date("end_date")) \
  .withColumn(
    "lineofdate", 
     F.expr("""sequence(start_date,end_date,interval 1 day)""") \
  ) \
  .show()

# output: 
# +----------+----------+--------------------+
# |start_date|  end_date|          lineofdate|
# +----------+----------+--------------------+
# |2020-02-01|2020-03-21|[2020-02-01, 2020...|
# +----------+----------+--------------------+
```